# How to see the file revisions in Tux3 and NILFS?

Tags: files, filesystems, data

Tux3 and NilFS are file systems made for file history/revisions.

#### How can I see these revisions?

On Windows, there is a file history manager and Shadow Copies (enabled by default only on Windows 7 and Vista Business/higher). 
That is no native NTFS feature, however.